# Ruby version did not get updated to 1.9.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed ruby as per instructions given [here](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/) but when I do ruby--version then it still shows 1.8.7. How do I make sure I use newly installed Ruby?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use RVM (Ruby Version Manager). You may find a full installation guide here:

http://ryanbigg.com/2011/06/mac-os-x-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

If you get an error such as "ERROR: Error running ' ./configure...." after executing rvm install e.g.

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Then you may try to install it like this:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Note: in the guide this possible error is not described

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly setup your `PATH`? What's the output of `echo $PATH`? `/usr/local/bin` has to come first they way this tutorial sets up things. You see that everything worked right when `which ruby` displays `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.

Personally I'd recommend using a tool for managing Ruby versions though. [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) still seems to be the most popular choice, I prefer the combination of [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build).